# main function is not defined

Tags: pic, pid-controller

I am trying to build this code on MicroC using Pic16f877. It is a code using Kp and Ki values to control a motor. But when building, i keep getting the error main function is not defined.
Below is the code:

```
#ifdef PID_H
#define PID_H

#define epsilon 0.01 //time elapsed before the next loop
#define Max 5
#define Min -5       //for saturation

#define dt 0.01
#define kp 20.0
#define ki 1.0
#define kd 0
void main(float output){
float PIcal(float setpoint, float actual_voltage);
{
  float pre_error = 0.0;
  float integral = 0.0;
  float error;
  float output;
  float actual_voltage;
  float setpoint = 5.0;
  TRISA.F0 = 1; //Configure 1st bit of PORTD as input
  setpoint = TRISA.F0; //setpoint is the input
  TRISA.F1 = 1;
  TRISB.F0 = 0; //Makes PORTB0 or RB0 Output Pin(forward motion of the motor)
 TRISB.F1 = 0; //Makes PORTB1 or RB0 Output Pin(reverse motion of the motor)
 {
//calculate P,I
  error = setpoint - actual_voltage;

//if error is greater than the epsilon
  if(error > epsilon)
  {
   integral = integral + error*dt;
  }
   output = kp*error + ki*integral;

 //saturation filter
  if(output > Max)
  {
   output = Max;
   }
  else if (output < Min)
  {
   output = Min;
  }

  if (output > 0)
  {
   TRISB.F0 = 1; //forward rotation of the motor
   }
   if (output < 0)
   {
    TRISB.F1 = 1; //reverse rotation of the motor
    }

   }
}
#endif
```

Comment: I mean, do you understand every line of code in here, Massabe? What does the first line **do**?

Comment: Massabe, I'm sorry but you need to start off with a basic course on how to write a C program for a microcontroller. You probably think you're asking a 'how do I fix this little bug' question, but the code you've posted shows that you're really don't know how C 'works'.

Comment: You don't declare and define functions inside other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1.

Your #endif is at the end of the block of code. Essentially you are telling the compiler not to compile anything if PID_H is NOT defined.

Try using

```
#ifndef PID_H
```

instead of

```
#ifdef PID_H
```

Point 2.

You can't declare PIcal() inside main()!
Use something like...

```
...

float PIcal (float setpoint, float actual_voltage) ;

void main(float output)
{
     float pre_error = 0.0 ;
     float integral = 0.0 ;
     float error ;
     ...
```

Comment: hm, `main` inside a file that would, if this include guard was actually sensible, be a header to be included elsewhere? Sounds unlikely. This looks like OP was copying together code without much thought. I greatly appreciate you helping, but I don't think the "copy, paste, ask question without thinking" approach will get them anywhere

Comment: @MarcusMüller The Stack Overflow blog actually had a related article not so long ago: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/26/copying-code-from-stack-overflow-you-might-be-spreading-security-vulnerabilities/

Comment: @MarcusMüller, so true. But in my community Q&A experience, the very worst kind of answer to give anyone is the question "Why would you want to do that"? So I thought it best to try to give a purely technical answer the OP's question, hoping they know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
float PIcal(float setpoint, float actual_voltage);
{
```

1. In above statement just delete {,
2. Delete  one } at the end of your main function
3. Define the function

```
float PIcal (float setpoint, float actual_voltage)
{
    .....
}
```

above and outside the main function